# Blockchain prereqs

Tags: blockchain, react

I know there are many job boards for web3 that display the job requirements but I just wanted to know from someone who has experience working in this field about the proficiency one needs in React. Are only full-stack devs preferred or are there openings for only smart contract devs who understand react code but aren't good at it/ don't want to work on it?